# using python unable to insert pandas dataframe to teradata table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have to push data from pandas dataframe to teradata table using python

tried different methods **teradatasql** , **pyodbc**, **sqlalchemy** , **teradata.UdaExec** but am getting unique errors for each method

Below are the codes & errors

```
  Code 1:
   host,user,password ='SMASUN.UPC','J3E186','admin123'
   database, table_name='Supply', 'AD_Products'
   con= teradatasql.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, 
   database=database)
   sam=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Desktop/products.csv")
   sam.to_sql(table_name, con=con, index=False, if_exists="replace")

 Error 1:
  OperationalError: [Version 17.20.0.19] [Session 34249729] [Teradata Database] [Error 3707] Syntax error, 
   expected something like a 'CHECK' keyword between '(' and the 'exp' keyword.
   at gosqldriver/teradatasql.formatError ErrorUtil.go:89
 

 Code 2:
       tera_engine= create_engine('teradata://'+ user +':' + password + '@'+ host + 
   ':22/')
      #tera_engine
     df='`SELECT * FROM `fucntional_.supply.products`' [this is from big query directly pushing to teradata]
     connection=tera_engine.connect()
     connection.execute(df)
     connection.close()

 Error 2:
  DatabaseError: (1207, '[HY000] [TPT][ODBC PostgreSQL Wire Protocol driver]Connection refused. Verify Host Name and Port Number.
 , [TPT][ODBC PostgreSQL Wire Protocol driver]Invalid attribute in connection string: DBCNAME.')

 Code 3:
      df=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Desktop/products.csv")
      table_name = 'products'
     # Insert the dataframe into the table using executemany
      insert_query = f"insert into {table_name} values (?, ?)"
      values = [tuple(row) for row in df.values.tolist()]
      cursor.executemany(insert_query, values)
     con.commit()
     con.close()

 Error 3:
 InterfaceError: ('28000', '[28000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] (210) The UserId, 
Password or Account is invalid.FailCode = -8017 (210) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] (210) 
       The UserId, Password or Account is invalid. FailCode = -8017 (210)')
```

Comment: as per the final error message you'll double-check the username and password, right?

Comment: @mechanical_meat Yes but it was right credentials

Comment: Problem with `teradatasql` is likely due to having SqlAlchemy v2.0 installed; downgrade to v1.4 and that issue should go away. Problem with `teradata` driver is that it is using "Teradata x.x PostgreSQL Wire Protocol" driver when it should be something like "Teradata Database ODBC Driver xx.yy" or possibly just "Teradata" (since the third one looks like you may have a very old version of Teradata ODBC installed - in addition to some issue with the credentials). Remove the port :22 suffix, and add Driver= to pick up the proper ODBC.

Comment: @Fred : am using `SqlAlchemy 1.4.39 version` but still code 1 issue still showing up.

Comment: OK, then the issue is most likely that your dataframe has a column named "exp" which is a reserved word in Teradata. Rename that column, e.g. `sam.rename(columns={'exp':'exp_'}, inplace=True)`

Comment: @Fred : For the first error which i shown above still am unable to resolve , I can see dataframe output but  when am trying to push teradata using `to_sql`. am getting `OperationalError: [Version 17.20.0.19] [Session 34501542] [Teradata Database] [Error 3707] Syntax error, expected something like '(' between the 'type' keyword and '='. `

Comment: below to that same command another error is shown up `DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': [Version 17.20.0.19] [Session 34501542] [Teradata Database] [Error 3707] Syntax error, expected something like '(' between the 'type' keyword and '='.
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.formatError ErrorUtil.go:8`

Comment: type is also reserved word.

Comment: That looks like a metadata query for sqlalchemy's default SQLite database. You may need to install `teradatasqlalchemy` and/or explicitly create an "engine" object using `teradatasql://` as the dialect.

Comment: @Andrew: but there is no word type i have used how come it was showing error

Comment: SQLAlchemy generates additional SQL requests "under the covers", e.g. to check whether the table already exists, and in this case it was using the wrong dialect for that - one which uses a column named "type".

Comment: @Fred : can you explain in brief with example how to resolve am unable to understand what you mention in above comment. never mind.